# parsing object output data in PHP

Tags: php

```
$location = '{ latitude: (location tatitude), longitude: (location longitude), description: (location description) }';

$json = json_decode($location,true);

$locationlat = $json['latitude'];
```

I want to pull the latitude data in php. Blank data comes when I do it this way. How can I pull latitude and long data?

Comment: That's not valid JSON.  It will not decode.

Comment: It's not JSON, but you can do something like that : `preg_match('/{ latitude: (.*), longitude: (.*), description: (.*)}/', $location, $matches);`. Results in `$matches`.

Answer (score -1):

In your **$location** is not a valid JSON
So **json_decode** return **null**.

try

```php
$location = '{ latitude: "location tatitude", longitude: "location longitude", description: "location description" }';
```

Comment: The data is coming directly baby, the way I wrote it, I have no chance to fix it

Comment: Then you need to do something else, it is not JSON.

Comment: So if you want to use JSON you will need to parse it first.

Answer (score -1):

First, the JSON code is wrong. JSON should look like this:

```json
{
     "fooString": "barString",
     "fooObject": {
          "barString": "Hello World"
     }
}
```

Now... When you do `json_decode()`, it makes an object and you shall therefore retrieve a value like this:

```php
$json = json_decode($location);
$locationlat = $json->latitude;
```